# Install Linux without an installer: Can it be done?

Tags: system-installation, bios, asus

I have a machine with Lubuntu on a very old Mobo, Asus P5KC with Megatrends BIOS v 2.58, and, although I could swear I installed it from a USB pen, the BIOS won't recognize any as a boot device (the one I prepared works in other systems, it is just the BIOS that won't boot from the pendrive).
Before doing heroic things without value, like finding where to burn a DVD, install a DVD reader in my machine and boot from it, I have asked myself if I could simply install it from my working Lubuntu in another partition on my system, adjust the boot records and grub and just restart the machine. Looks as an interesting enough project but I feel I do no have the necessary knowledge (I used to do that a lot in mainframes, build a system volume from scratch).
Can anybody shed some light on me, or alternatively, tell me what happens with my motherboard?. Any help is appreciated.

P.S. I intend to install Linux Mint. Ubuntu 22.04 has lost its compass.

Comment: (For all practical purposes in this regard, lubuntu and mint are both just special cases of Debian)

Comment: Generally, there is *a lot* of answers here that address *installing Linux from Linux* (that's what I searched for); please do a bit mor own research next time! For example, also: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/361239/install-linux-from-linux

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/651990/can-i-install-another-linux-distribution-to-an-extra-hdd-without-rebooting

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/78250/can-i-install-a-distro-to-one-partition-while-using-a-distro-installed-on-anothe

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem myself. This motherboard and BIOS take the boot disk only from the first three ones listed. The USB pendrive appeared as the fourth one. Changed the order and then it appeared as selectable for boot.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can install a Linux system from another running Linux system (or similar OS) using shell.

See [ArchLinux Installation Guide](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Installation_guide). ArchLinux is a linux distribution that does not have an installer and the user has to perform all the steps manually. It is not very hard, if you understand what needs to be done to get a system running.

To install distributions using dpkg package tool/system can be installed using `debootstrap`. Internally, Debian, Devuan, Ubuntu or Linux Mint installers use this program to setup the system. Its usage is similar to Arch's `pacstrap`, but you need to specify also from where you want to install the system.

There is also [Linux From Scratch project](https://linuxfromscratch.org/) that aims to give instructions to install a system by building from source code, without use of utilities like `debootstrap` or `pacstrap`. It is a linux distribution, but the system is distributed by means of *book* (or webpage, if you want).

Practically all Linux systems can be installed just by copying the files and adjusting few things. Some distributions, like ArchLinux ARM, Gentoo or Raspbian are designed to be installed in this way. (The first two need assistance of the user, the last one performs the adjustments automatically.)